# GCC cross compilation tool for fedora

Tags: gcc, arm, fedora

I need to compile a code with gcc for ARMv7-A architecture on x86 system, how can i install tools on fedora?? 
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi package is not available in fedora and sudo dnf install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arm provides prebuilt GNU cross-toolchains which is available from developer.arm.com.

1. For A-profile cores - https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a
2. For R and M profile cores - https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm.

Hope that helps.